# Can all problems in mathematics be encoded using Gödel numbering?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

For example in his paper he defines codes for:

```
“0”     …   1
“f ”    …   3
“¬”     …   5
“∨”     …   7
“∀”     …   9
“(”     …   11
“)”     …   13
```

Is it possible for every mathematical statement to be formed using only these symbols e.g. Riemann's Hypothesis or the Twin Prime Conjecture, and how would these be encoded?

Or are these symbols just an example for simpler statements that could be encoded using such symbols, so to encode more complicated statements more symbols would have to be used but these could just be added to the list and would not affect the proof?

Comment: Every mathematical symbol and statement can be expressed in Gödel numbering.  It is convenient to include additional symbols as well.

Comment: Farthest thing from an answer here ... It might be interesting, at least for neophytes as myself, simply to see how one represents the Riemann zeta function in terms of Gödel numbering, if it's done so constructively or if it simply exists in principle. And then the conjecture, that would be fascinating. Following this question for sure, I might even learn something! Best of luck.

Comment: @Aruralreader: The process is as constructive as it can be (given that it's a matter of translating a description partially in natural language into a formal notation, so it necessarily depends on _understanding_ the original quasiformal notation). However the usually taught methods are not optimized for size at all, so expressing something as complex as the Riemann hypothesis would lead to a _huge_ Gödel number. One can come up with more economic representations, though.

Comment: Gödel was concerned with a language of arithmetic formulas over the integers (Peano Arithmetic, or PA). PA is can express the twin prime conjecture, but not the Riemann hypothesis. The language of set theory can express both, and can be Gödelised just like the language of PA. But note that this isn't really surprising. It is no more than the observation that the languages in question are countable in a constructive way. The key point is the fact that a language that is strong enough to talk about arithmetic is strong enough to talk about itself - that was Gödel's amazing insight.

Comment: ... actually Gödel original paper dealt with the system of Russell and Whiteheads *Principia Mathematica* (which should be strong enough to express both the twin primes conjecture and the Riemann hypothesis).  That doesn't affect the main issue here: the arithmetization of syntax is not a big deal, but realizing what that meant for logical systems was an enormous break-through.

Comment: On the other hand, _Principia Mathematica_ was already somewhere between old hat and obsolete by the time of Gödel's paper. My understanding is that he targeted PM mainly as a way to drive the point home that incompleteness is not a specific failing of first-order logic _in particular_ (and Gödel himself had had a great share in defining and polishing FOL over the preceding years), but is a general property of essentially _all_ symbols-on-paper games.

Comment: @Troposphere: I don't understand the relevance of your (very interesting) comment to this thread. I simply added my comment mentioning *Principia Mathematica*, because my earlier comment was a little misleading about the actual subject matter of Gödel's original published work on incompleteness.

Comment: @RobArthan: Apologies -- I'm not sure I _had_ a cogent/relevant point to make, just a bit of freewheeling association to your mention of PM.

Comment: @Troposphere: I see. No worries. My "freewheeling association" is that R&W's PM was far from obsolete, but just a little neglected (although luminaries like Gödel recognised its relevance). It gave birth to Church's simple type theory and then led on to the plethora of type theories that have become so important in proof theory, reverse mathematics, category theory, computer science and ...